# No Graphene or Lineage support...am I stuck carrying a google-tracker now? (LG "Journey" on Tracfone)

Tags: google, privacy

I prefer flip phones but now I need web access while on job-site, I don't know why I thought I could just put Lineage onto any handset (swore you could just root a phone and put a new OS on, didn't recall it being model-specific but haven't used smartphones for nearly a decade)

What can I do to eliminate, or reduce if that's all I can do, my "google footprint" here?  I've used ADB to remove every package with "google" in the title but that doesn't remove *all* the google stuff (and some of it simply cannot be removed, one of them - if removed - makes it so the phone will go into an endless loop upon reboot, requiring a full hard-reset)

Thanks a ton for any advice, I know about F-Droid and am using the duckduckgo browser and FOSS alternatives to, say, Calendar adn Youtube-viewer but the fact it's still on this device/hardware that seems to have "Google" tattoo'd to its bones is bothersome, any & all things I can do to ameliorate this would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: If you want a Google free Android device you have to plan this before buying, read reviews, tutorials and user comments to find the best device. Note that nearly every web page also contains Google and/or other trackers. Therefore the only way to live Google free is not to use anything web or Android related. Nowadays you can only decide how many data you give to trackers like Google. Totally preventing is next to impossible.

Comment: you can reset your google advertising id from settings every day

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/225549